# SharePoint 2013 non-HA Farm with App Services

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-mobile-services

I'm very new to Azure so be kind :)

I have a new and bare VM running 'SharePoint 2013 non-HA Farm' setup and deployed and it seems to be running ok.

Now what I was wondering is if I could setup an App in 'App Services' and then connect to the SharePoint 2013 SQL VM that Azure created during the deployment.

Currently if I try and select and existing database in the App settings I only see the normal SQL DBs I guess because the VM DB isn't exposed to the Azure platform.

I could of course create a link manually between the SQL and the APP but Id rather keep it inside of Azure if you know what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will have to connect to the app "manually" but you can integrate your app to the VNet used by your VM to avoid going out on the internet for your network communication between each other.

To enable VNET Integration open your app Settings and then select Networking.
The VNET Integration UI allows you to select from a list of your VNETs. The V1 VNETs will indicate that they are such with the word "Classic" in parenthesis next to the VNET name. The list is sorted such that the V2 VNETs are listed first.

More info here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/#enabling-vnet-integration

Comment: Wonderful thank you. Ill take a look and get back! :)

Comment: So I'm getting there....

Everything seems logical until you go into the VNET integration area and try to connect the Virtual Network and the app together. It complained that the pre-setup SharePoint Virtual Network didn't have a gateway. Which I then diligently setup via the Virtual Network Gateways blade. I then go back into the VNET integration and now although a gateway is active it doesn't have a Point-to-Site Address Block. Nowhere did it ask or tell me how to set this up. I think i'm one step from joining the two...

Comment: The answer is in the link I provided. You will find a section named "Enable Point to Site in a VNET". Steps are describded for V1 Vnet & V2 VNet. Version depends on the type of VM you created : classic (V1) or ARM (V2)

Comment: :) Thank you Im getting there!